# Lazy loading python sub-modules, importlib fails first time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm experimenting with the idea of lazy-loading of symbols in a package's `__init__.py` by subclassing `ModuleType` and defining properties for each of the submodules. Accessing the symbol in the package namespace would trigger the import. I've got it working, but for some reason, my call to `import_module` fails on the first attempt and I don't understand why.

I have a minimal example. Assume a package like this:

```
my_package:
    __init__.py
    m1.py
```

this is the `__init__.py`

```
import sys
import importlib
from types import ModuleType


class MyModule(ModuleType):
    @property
    def m1(self):
        try:
            _m1 = importlib.import_module('.m1', __package__)
        except AttributeError:
            print('second try ...')
            _m1 = importlib.import_module('.m1', __package__)

        return _m1


old = sys.modules[__name__]
new = MyModule(__name__)
new.__path__ = old.__path__

for k, v in list(old.__dict__.items()):
    new.__dict__[k] = v

sys.modules[__name__] = new
```

The `import_module` call always fails with an `AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'm1'`. However, the second call always succeeds. In other words, when I do `my_package.m1` I always get `m1`, but it always prints `'second try ...'`.

Note, the behavior is dependent on python version. The call to `import_lib` works fine the first time on python2.7.

Comment: Did you inspect the traceback from the `AttributeError`? Re-write as `except AttributeError as error` and call the `logger.exception(error)`.

Comment: Check this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception. Paste the traceback in your question. It'll certainly be helpful in debugging.

Comment: @RenatoByrro yeah, of course. That's how I know to do the try/except in the first place. This is the exception:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-26b8e7fa2688> in <module>()
----> 1 my_package.m1

AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'm1'

Comment: @RenatoByrro, to clarify, the AttributeError is the whole traceback. There isn't anything more to post than what I put into the original question.

Comment: Yes, I replicated and it really doesn't help much. By running it directly from CLI I get a slightly more verbose traceback, but nothing helpful. It's really strange, I guess it's related to how Python importing is structured under the hood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the difference between python2 vs python3.

In python3, the `importlib.import_module` call ultimately ends up
[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L959)
which is a call to `setattr`. Since you didn't define a `.setter` for
your property, you get the `AttributeError`.

In python2, the `importlib.import_module` call ends up
[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/importlib/__init__.py#L37)
which is a call to the builtin `__import__` which presumably operates
directly on the module `__dict__`.

The only question is how in the world it ever works in python3. I
would have thought it would *always* resulted in a `AttributeError`.

Your code works fine as long as you make a `.setter`:

```
@m1.setter
def m1(self, mod):
    self.__dict__['m1'] = mod
```

It actually turns out that the `.setter` can do anything at all,
including `pass` since you are unconditionally making the call to
`import_module`.

I would consider using the `.setattr` above and changing the getter to:

```
@property
def m1(self):
    if not self.__dict__.get('m1'):
        self.__dict__['m1'] = importlib.import_module('.m1', __package__)
    return self.__dict__['m1']
```